# LWC issue in binding the lightning combo box

Tags: apex, lightning, lightning-web-components, picklist

I am using LWC in a screen flow. I get a response from an API and need to bind that value in the lightning combo box. It's in the JSON array format. Here is the code.

**JS**

```
 import { 
    LightningElement,
    track,
    wire,
    api
     
} from 'lwc';

    import getCooridinatesFromPinCode from '@salesforce/apex/ChurchNearYouController.getCooridinatesFromPinCode';
    import { FlowAttributeChangeEvent } from 'lightning/flowSupport';
    
    export default class ChurchNearYouComponent extends LightningElement {
        @api postalCode;
        @api selectedChurch;
        @track churchDropDown = [];
        @track value;
        
        @wire(getCooridinatesFromPinCode, { postalCode: '$postalCode'})
        wiredChurchList({ error, data }) {
            if (data) {
                console.log(data);
                this.churchDropDown = data;
            }
        }
    
        get churchList() {
            console.log('Get' + this.churchDropDown);
            return this.churchDropDown;
            /*return [
                { label: 'St James Piccadilly', value: '623055' },
                { label: 'St Anne Soho', value: '623058' },
                { label: 'St Paul Covent Garden', value: '623070' },
            ];*/
    
            //return [{"value":623055,"label":"St James Piccadilly"},{"value":623058,"label":"St Anne Soho"},{"value":623070,"label":"St Paul Covent Garden"},{"value":623065,"label":"St Martin-in-the-Fields"},{"value":823011,"label":"Guards Chapel of Wellington Barracks"}];
        }
    
        /*set churchList(val){
            console.log('Set' + val);
            this.churchDropDown = val;
        }*/
       
    
        handleChange(event) {
            const attributeChangeEvent = new FlowAttributeChangeEvent('selectedChurch', event.detail.value);
            this.dispatchEvent(attributeChangeEvent);
        }
    
    }
```

**HTML**

```
<lightning-combobox
    name="ChurchListSource" 
    label="Church" value={value}
    placeholder="-Select-"
    options={churchList} onchange={handleChange}>
</lightning-combobox>
<lightning-formatted-text value={churchList} ></lightning-formatted-text>
```

**Apex**

```
    /**
 * @description       : Class to get the church near by using latitude and longitude
 * @author            : Vetriselvan Manoharan
 * @last modified on  : 09-17-2021
 * @last modified by  : Vetriselvan Manoharan
**/
public class ChurchNearYouController {


    /**
    * @description Method to get the geolocation details using the postal codes
    * @author Vetriselvan Manoharan | 09-10-2021 
    * @param postalCode 
    **/
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable = true)
    public static String getCooridinatesFromPinCode(String postalCode){
        List<ChurchListWrapper> churchWrapperList = new List<ChurchListWrapper>();
        String ancyResults = '';
        Geolocation_API_Details__c geoLocation = Geolocation_API_Details__c.getOrgDefaults();
        String restAPIURL = geoLocation.Callout_URL__c;
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setMethod('GET'); 
        req.setEndpoint(restAPIURL+'/'+postalCode); 
        try 
        {  
            Http http = new Http();   
            HttpResponse httpResponse = http.send(req);  
            if (httpResponse.getStatusCode() == 200) 
            { 
                PostCodeIOWrapper postCodeResponse = (PostCodeIOWrapper) System.JSON.deserialize(httpResponse.getBody(), PostCodeIOWrapper.class);
                if(!Test.isRunningTest()) {
                    ancyResults = getChurchNearYou(postCodeResponse.result.latitude,postCodeResponse.result.longitude);
                    ANCYWrapper ancyResponse = (ANCYWrapper) System.JSON.deserialize(ancyResults, ANCYWrapper.class);   
                    //insertorUpdateChurchestoDiocese(ancyResponse.results);
                    churchWrapperList = getChurchListDropDown(ancyResponse.results);
                    System.debug('Church Wrapper List' + churchWrapperList);
                    System.debug(JSON.serialize(churchWrapperList));
                    return JSON.serialize(churchWrapperList);
                }
            } 
            else 
            {  
                System.debug(' httpResponse ' + httpResponse.getBody() );  
                throw new CalloutException( httpResponse.getBody() );
            } 
            return '';
        } 
        catch( System.Exception e) 
        {  
            System.debug('ERROR: '+ e);  
            throw e; 
        } 
    }

    /**
    * @description Method to get the churches near you using the geolocation
    * @author Vetriselvan Manoharan | 09-08-2021 
    * @param latitude 
    * @param longitude 
    **/
    public static String getChurchNearYou(Double latitude, Double longitude){
        ANCY_API_Details__c ancy = ANCY_API_Details__c.getOrgDefaults();
        String authToken = ancy.Access_token__c;
        String restAPIURL = ancy.Callout_URL__c;
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setHeader('Authorization', 'Token ' + authToken);
        req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        req.setHeader('Accept', '*/*');
        req.setMethod('GET');
        req.setEndpoint(restAPIURL+'?id=&is_church=true&church_reference=&is_school=&name=&country=&phone_number=&website_url=&updated_at=&filter_geo_lat='+latitude+'&filter_geo_lon='+longitude+'&filter_geo_radius=0.5');
        try 
        {  
            Http http = new Http();   
            HttpResponse httpResponse = http.send(req);  
            if (httpResponse.getStatusCode() == 200 ) 
            {  
                return httpResponse.getBody();
            } 
            else 
            {  
                throw new CalloutException( httpResponse.getBody() );  
            }   
        } 
        catch( System.Exception e) 
        {  
            System.debug('ERROR: '+ e);  
            throw e;  
        } 
    }

    /**
    * @description Insert or update church and relate to Diocese
    * @author Vetriselvan Manoharan | 09-15-2021 
    * @param ancyResponse 
    **/
    public static void insertorUpdateChurchestoDiocese( List<ANCYWrapper.results> ancyResponse ) {
        List<Church__c> churchList = new List<Church__c>();
        Map<String,Id> dioceseMap = new Map<String,Id>();

        // Get the list of dioceses
        if(Diocese__c.SObjectType.getDescribe().isAccessible()) {
            List<Diocese__c> dioceseList  = [ SELECT Id, ACNY_Id__c FROM Diocese__c ];
            for( Diocese__c diocese : dioceseList ) {
                dioceseMap.put(diocese.ACNY_Id__c,diocese.Id);
            }
        }

        for( ANCYWrapper.results ancy : ancyResponse ){
            Church__c churchToUpsert = new Church__c();
            churchToUpsert.Diocese__c = dioceseMap.get(String.valueOf(ancy.church.diocese));
            churchToUpsert.Name = ancy.church.name;
            churchToUpsert.ACNY_Id__c = String.valueOf(ancy.church.id);
            churchList.add(churchToUpsert);
        }

        // Insert or update the churches
        if(churchList.size() > 0 && Church__c.SObjectType.getDescribe().isAccessible()){
            Database.UpsertResult[] results = Database.upsert(churchList, Church__c.ACNY_Id__c);
            System.debug(results);
        } 
    }

    /**
    * @description 
    * @author Vetriselvan Manoharan | 09-17-2021 
    * @param ancyResponse 
    * @return List<ChurchListWrapper> 
    **/
    public static List<ChurchListWrapper> getChurchListDropDown( List<ANCYWrapper.results> ancyResponse ){
        List<ChurchListWrapper> churchWrapperList = new List<ChurchListWrapper>();
        for( ANCYWrapper.results ancy : ancyResponse ){
            ChurchListWrapper churchDropDown = new ChurchListWrapper();
            churchDropDown.label = ancy.church.name;
            churchDropDown.value = ancy.church.id;
            churchWrapperList.add(churchDropDown);
        }
        return churchWrapperList;
    }


    public class ChurchListWrapper {
        String label;
        Integer value;
    }
}
```

If I hard code the json array and return then it binding the combo-box but when returing the churchDropDown it is not working as expected. I can see the response in the text value but not getting binded on the dropdown.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: please provide code of `getCooridinatesFromPinCode` apex method

Comment: Yes, add the controller code.. It returns a JSON array! the method basically performs callout and get the response back.. I serialize the response

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are returning serialized `String` and assigning `String` to the js property. Js expecting to have here an array of JSON objects, but not just `String`.

You have two options.

- deserialize returned String by `getCooridinatesFromPinCode`;
- return not `String` with the serialization of the list of objects, but `List<ChurchListWrapper>`, lwc framework will do the rest for you.

I prefer the second option. Apex `getCooridinatesFromPinCode` should look like:

```
@AuraEnabled(cacheable = true)
public static List<ChurchListWrapper> getCooridinatesFromPinCode(String postalCode){
    List<ChurchListWrapper> churchWrapperList = new List<ChurchListWrapper>();
    String ancyResults = '';
    Geolocation_API_Details__c geoLocation = Geolocation_API_Details__c.getOrgDefaults();
    String restAPIURL = geoLocation.Callout_URL__c;
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.setMethod('GET'); 
    req.setEndpoint(restAPIURL+'/'+postalCode); 
    try 
    {  
        Http http = new Http();   
        HttpResponse httpResponse = http.send(req);  
        if (httpResponse.getStatusCode() == 200) 
        { 
            PostCodeIOWrapper postCodeResponse = (PostCodeIOWrapper) System.JSON.deserialize(httpResponse.getBody(), PostCodeIOWrapper.class);
            if(!Test.isRunningTest()) {
                ancyResults = getChurchNearYou(postCodeResponse.result.latitude,postCodeResponse.result.longitude);
                ANCYWrapper ancyResponse = (ANCYWrapper) System.JSON.deserialize(ancyResults, ANCYWrapper.class);   
                //insertorUpdateChurchestoDiocese(ancyResponse.results);
                churchWrapperList = getChurchListDropDown(ancyResponse.results);
                System.debug('Church Wrapper List' + churchWrapperList);
                System.debug(JSON.serialize(churchWrapperList));
                return JchurchWrapperList;
            }
        } 
        else 
        {  
            System.debug(' httpResponse ' + httpResponse.getBody() );  
            throw new CalloutException( httpResponse.getBody() );
        } 
    } 
    catch( System.Exception e) 
    {  
        System.debug('ERROR: '+ e);  
        throw e; 
    } 
}
```

and make properties of your wrapper `ChurchListWrapper` class aura enabled

```
public class ChurchListWrapper {
    @AuraEnabled
    public String label {get; set;}
    @AuraEnabled
    public Integer value {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: that worked.. thank you!